# Chat bot on Multiple Communities

Tags: community, salesforcedx, einstein, bots

I've Einstein Bot which is running smoothly on a single community now. but in the future, I want to configure the Bot on multiple Community sites? Is there any way to do that?

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any issue with putting the same bot on multiple communities. You'll have to just drag and drop the Embedded Service Component on other communities too - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bot_cookbook.meta/bot_cookbook/bot_cookbook_greet_customer_lex.htm